# python incorporate png/ico to exe and use it in application

Tags: python, image, icons, png, exe

I am zsing py2exe to compile exe files. I would like to incorporate png and icon file into exe and then use it during program run (to show it in about dialog and system tray). How can I do it?

For example now I use self.staticon.set_from_file(os.path.join(module_path(), "icon.ico")) but I would like to prevent user from changeing this icon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to build an installer with Innosetup ( http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) , where you can specify icons for your software and icons for files depending on your software. In the end you have to modify the registry and Innosetup does this for you.